# read and convert plist data into String (Swift)

Tags: string, swift, plist

I realize there are other questions about this already. But I'm trying to return a value I read from a plist as a String and it says:

```
'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'
```

Here is what I have:

```
func getWord () -> String {
    let wordList = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: "mylist.plist")
    return wordList.objectForKey("team")
}
```

plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>team</key>
    <array>
        <string>outfielder</string>
        <string>pitcher</string>
        <string>shortstop</string>
        <string>coach</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: The value of the "team" key in your plist is an array, not a string.

Comment: good point. I found my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast it to String.

```
func getWord () -> String {
    let wordList = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: "mylist.plist")
    return wordList.objectForKey("team") as String
}
```

But be careful. You are returning the implicitly unwrapped optional. If you don't have value for the "team" key, your app will crash. It will also crash if the value for that key is not String, because we are using forced casting here.

Comment: this would be the best answer if I would have asked it right

Answer (score 1):

Try to add string at the end:

```
wordList.objectForKey("team").string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var path: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bhsCustom", ofType: "plist")!

// Get host link from plist
let wordList = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
var webLink: NSString = wordList.objectForKey("about_bhs") as NSString
```